# Change coordinate order in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I want to change the order of entering coordinates in TikZ.

In 2D-coordinates it is (x,y) as in (right/left, up/down).
As soon as I enter a third coordinate, TikZ just adds the third coordinate at the end.
It is then (left/right, up/down, front/back)
Is it possible to change the format of entering coordinates to
(front/back, left/right, up/down)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shadows,trees, decorations.markings, positioning, patterns, plotmarks, 
matrix,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,shapes.symbols,chains, 3D, calc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above]{$x$};
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[left]{$y$};
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left]{$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}   

    \vspace{5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above]{$y$};
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[left]{$z$};
                \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left]{$x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to do a circular permutation so that the first entered coordinate is the x coordinate as in the second example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `xyz` coordinate system can be configured, by specifying `xy canvas` vectors for `x`, `y`, and `z`. The examples defines the style `yzx` with a different mapping for the coordinate components:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{yzx} = [
  x={(-.385cm, -.385cm)},
  y={(1cm, 0cm)},
  z={(0cm, 1cm)},
]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[left]{$y$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left]{$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yzx, scale=1.5]
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[left]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above]{$y$};
        \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left]{$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]